# Converting Iterator[String] to String

Tags: scala

I have an Iterator[String] that I want to convert to a String in Scala. I would expect the following to work, but I get no output. What am I doing wrong?

```
val it = Iterator("a", "number", "of", "words")
val combined = "";

while (it.hasNext){
   combined = combined + it.next()
}
println(combined)
```

Comment: I hope it does not even compile. :) You try to reassign a `val`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your code can't even compile, since you're reassigning a `val`

```
it.mkString
```

will do what you're after

Comment: I think you can even leave out the `("")`. It should be the default.